# Replace SubString on Partial match of word

Tags: c#

I have two strings :-

```
String S1 = "This is my\r\n string."
String S2 = "This is my\n self."
```

I want to have a generic method to replace any existence of "\n" to "\r\n". But it should not replace any part of the string if it already has "\r\n".

Comment: Have you tried anything to implement that functionality? Share it with us, even if it didn't work we can still give pointers.

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: Just thought I'd add to Tim's comment. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You've basically used us to write code for you so I suspect that's why you are getting so many downvotes on your question. You should include your own code in your question and then you won't get the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression with [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");
```

It matches all `\n` which are not preceded by `\r`.

Comment: While specific to the language, this should be the best solution. A good use case for regex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have well-behaved standard input text, i.e. no consecutive `\r`, you can simply use:

```
var result = S1.replace("\n","\r\n").replace("\r\r","\r")
```

This won't work in general cases, obviously

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using a simple replace?

Comment: This is a simple replace, other options would be regex replace, or split and join

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Not even a simple regex can do this easily, you would have to resort to domain-specific regex or to a somewhat lengthy general regex.

Comment: Never said simple regex did I? Think I'd split by ['\r','\n'] then join with environment.newline

Comment: I was referring to the first comment by user1061404, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var unused = "§";
S2 =
    S2
        .Replace("\r\n", unused)
        .Replace("\n", unused)
        .Replace(unused, "\r\n");
```

Comment: You could also try to extract the 'unused' string by parsing the source string to avoid problems when the source contains `§`. However, then again, if you go to that length, you could just as well go and write a specialized method to take care of this :)

Comment: @mafu - That was why I called the variable `unused` because it needs to be "unused" in the source text.